# How do I get rid of the commas in the following JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code:

```
var fileChapters = (function() {
  var results = [];
  for (i = 0, len = posts.length; i < len; _i++) {
    var post = posts[i];
    results.push("<p><a href=\"#chap1\">" + post.title + "</a></p>\n\n");
  }
  return results;
});
```

console log to `fileChapters`:

`["<p><a href="#chap1">Post 1</a></p>↵↵", "<p><a href="#chap1">Post 2</a></p>↵↵", "<p><a href="#chap1">Untitled</a></p>↵↵", "<p><a href="#chap1">Untitled</a></p>↵↵", "<p><a href="#chap1">Untitled</a></p>↵↵"]`

Now when I do push:

```
file.unshift fileTOC
```

I end up with the following HTML:

```
  <p><a href="#chap1">Post 1</a></p>

,<p><a href="#chap1">Post 2</a></p>

,<p><a href="#chap1">Untitled</a></p>

,<p><a href="#chap1">Untitled</a></p>

,<p><a href="#chap1">Untitled</a></p>
```

What's happening here? And how to solve it?

Comment: Try `fileChapters.join('')`

Answer (score 3):

It is an array, it has commas when you do toString()

If you do not want the commas, use

```
return results.join("");
```